# Determining if the set is a basis for the vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have determined that the vector set is linearly independent. The dim(s)=1. There are 4 vectors given. The only thing I do not understand is how with this info, I determine whether the given set is a basis for the vector space. S =(1 2 −5 4), (2 −7 6 2),(0 1 3 2),(0 1 2 0), V = R^2x2. So the vector space is R^2x2.

Answer (score 1):

Let V be a vector space, in your case $\mathbb{R}^4$. A linearly independent spanning set for V is called a basis. You have to show that $S$ is linearly independent and that it spans $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: S is linearly independent. How do I know if it spans R^4?

Comment: Given the vectors in $S$ can you get to any point in $\mathbb{R}^4$ ? In other words, can any vector $v \in V$ be represented as a linear combination of the vectors in $S$.